# How can I detect when the Windows 8 start screen opens using Java?

Tags: java, windows-8

I'm developing some sharing screen app and I need to detect if Windows 8 start screen is opened. If this is true i don't want to share screen.
**Is it possible to check this using some Java frameworks?**

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can detect the start screen however you can get the OS name using `System.getProperty("os.name")`. You can use this code

```
class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```